# Sort by type in ractive

Tags: ractivejs

I come across the tutorial part: http://learn.ractivejs.org/list-sections/5/

Made attempts with select and sort.

Ractive template

```
<th class='sortable {{ sortColumn === type ? "sorted" : "" }}' on-tap='sort:type'>
    <div class="industry select">
      <select>
        {{#each type}}
          <option> {{this}} </option>
        {{/each}}
      </select>
    </div>
</th>
```

HTML

```
<div data-list></div>
```

Ractive script

```
var type = ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Hamster'];
var ractive = new Ractive({
  el: document.querySelector('[data-list]'),
  template: '#list-container',
  data: {
    type: type,
    sort: function ( array, column ) {

          return array.sort( function ( a, b ) {
          return a[ column ] - b[ column ];
     });
    },
    sortColumn: 'type'
  }
})
```

Wanted to be able to select any type and then it sorts by type, say cats; it will list Cats and list with dog and hamster.

Any insight / help in ractive appreciated!

**Updated**

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z2z8z4cp/)

Currently it doesn't work because animal and sort is not correct I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to setup two-way binding on the `<select>` element, so that Ractive knows what the value of `sortColumn` should be:

```html
<select value='{{sortColumn}}'>
  {{#each type}}
    <option>{{this}}</option>
  {{/each}}
</select>
```

Comment: seems it is not doing anything..maybe {{ sortColumn === type ? "sorted" : "" }} is not right?

Comment: In your example, `type` is an array, so that definitely won't work. Can you post some sample data and your complete template (ideally in a JSFiddle so it's easy to debug and fork - [here's a template](http://jsfiddle.net/rich_harris/va6jU/)? Without that it's very hard to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have made jsfiddle above but still same result - animal cannot be sorted. If select cat, it would show all cats and other rest just line up after cat. Is there a way around?

Comment: Your template is just static markup - you need to use data-binding if you want it to re-render when things change: http://jsfiddle.net/rich_harris/ag2tLd6c/

Comment: many thanks. by data-binding you refer to {{selected}} and {{#each sort(animals,selected)}} correct? No wonder that it is not working right.

Comment: Yes - the idea behind templating systems is that the rendered output varies according to some input data. In the case of Ractive (and other systems based on Mustache templates), that means using `{{mustache}}` tags in place of static markup. The `value={{selected}}` is *two-way* binding - as well as data changes resulting in model->view changes, manipulating the `<select>` element results in view->model changes (which then trigger more model->view changes).

Comment: many thanks again. I hope to learn more ractive templating :) Thanks for your hard work on ractive